# Is it possible to not allow setting of a class property in TypeScript, but also throw a runtime error?

Tags: typescript

I have something like this:

```
class Computed<Value> {
  _value: Value;

  get value(){
    return this._value;
  }
}
```

When someone tries to set value, Typescript gives them an error: `Cannot assign to value because it is a read-only property.`

This is fine, but what if I also wanted a runtime check and throw an Error if someone tried to set the value ? Is that possible ?

Comment: Use a Proxy object

Comment:  It *does* give a runtime error, [at least when I try it](https://tsplay.dev/wEpxkW).  Did you try this and it doesn't give you a runtime error?  Or did you not try it before asking the question?

Comment: @jcalz you are using a private Javascript variable, OP's code is not. If you don't use the `#` then it does not error at runtime, paste `class Foo { _x = 3; get x() { return this._x; }};foo = new Foo(); foo.x = 5;` into your browser console, there's no error and the assignment silently fails. I mean, that's still probably best way to give OP what they want, but if they tried running their own code it wouldn't have errored.

Comment: @jcalz Just tried it and it works, thank you ! 
Do you think it would throw an Error even if private fields are not natively supported in the runtime it's running on ?

Comment: @JaredSmith this doesn't have anything to do with private fields, possibly it has to do with `"use strict"`. [Your code errors for me](https://tsplay.dev/N7VzBw)

Comment: It's [a feature of strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#failing_to_assign_to_object_properties).  If the runtime doesn't support strict mode then ‍♂️ I suppose you could write your own setter and throw in it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nry32w)

Comment: @jcalz good catch, I wrapped it in an IIFE with the pragma and sure enough it does error.

Comment: @DusanJovanov to reiterate from the convo back and forth between jcalz and myself, your original code from the question will already do what you want with no modifications as long as it's running in strict mode.

Comment: So, uh, how should we proceed here?  Just say "make sure you're using strict mode and this happens automatically"?  Or are we looking for some other answer?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct answer, at least for my purposes. You can post it and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using [JavaScript strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (either via the `"use strict"` directive or in contexts where strict mode is always enabled, like inside classes), then [there will be a runtime error when you try to assign to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#failing_to_assign_to_object_properties). Meaning your code, as written, will give the runtime error you're looking for:

```
"use strict";

class Computed<V> {
    _value: V;
    constructor(v: V) {
        this._value = v; // I added this so it's easier to initialize
    }
    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
}

const v = new Computed(123);

v.value = 2; // error
// compile-time error: Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property.
// also, RUNTIME ERROR!  TypeError: setting getter-only property "value"
```

---

If, for some reason, that's not sufficient, you could always explicitly create a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) that throws your desired error, at least since TypeScript 5.1 introduced support for [unrelated types for getters and setters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#unrelated-types-for-getters-and-setters), so the getter type stays the same, while the setter requires [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) so you can't call it at compile time either:

```
class Computed<V> {
    _value: V;
    constructor(v: V) {
        this._value = v;
    }
    set value(x: never) {
        throw new TypeError("hey, don't do that")
    }
    get value(): V { // explicitly annotate return type
        return this._value;
    }
}

const v = new Computed(123);
v.value = 2; // error
// compile-time error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
// also, RUNTIME ERROR!  TypeError: hey, don't do that
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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)